# Setting default desktop in CentOS 6.2

Tags: centos-6

In centos 4 and 5 I used to select desktop (KDE or Gnome) when I login and set if it's for this session only or permanent selection. In CentOS 6 I can also select desktop ... only after I enter my username (why?!?), but when I logout and login again the previous selection is active. How can I change default desktop ... since switchdesk is also gone.
I've searched for info and I found migration documents of Redhat. They say that switchdesk is gone, but they don't say how to set default desktop. Users don't have to know all ways to do a thing.

I also tried to use /etc/sysconfig/desktop ... but I ended up with KDE inside gnome! :) I hate when they remove features and call it "upgrade".